# Play JSON with sealed trait / case classes: infinite recursion

Tags: scala, playframework, traits, case-class, play-json

I have a code where I try to customize JSON serialization of a bunch of case classes by defining a custom Writes for the base trait. I'm getting infinite recursion / stack overflow.

I created a simplified sample - if somebody knows how to fix it, please let me know.

```
import play.api.libs.json._

sealed trait Person {
  val name: String
}

final case class Teacher(name: String, salary: Int) extends Person
final case class Student(name: String, grade: Int) extends Person

implicit val teacherWrites: Writes[Teacher] = Json.writes[Teacher]
implicit val studentWrites: Writes[Student] = Json.writes[Student]

val ThePersonWrites: Writes[Person] = Writes(person => {
  Json.writes[Person].writes(person).as[JsObject] - "_type"
})

implicit val personWrites: Writes[Person] = ThePersonWrites

val people = List[Person] (
  Teacher("Jane Doe", 40000),
  Student("Alice", 5),
  Student("Bob", 7)
  )

Json.prettyPrint(Json.toJson(people))
```

Comment: It should just work please paste the error details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need **[play-json-derived-codecs](https://github.com/julienrf/play-json-derived-codecs)**

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import julienrf.json.derived

sealed trait Person {
  val name: String
}

object Person {
  implicit val jsonFormat: OFormat[Person] = derived.oformat[Person]()
}

final case class Teacher(name: String, salary: Int) extends Person
final case class Student(name: String, grade: Int) extends Person


val people = List[Person] (
  Teacher("Jane Doe", 40000),
  Student("Alice", 5),
  Student("Bob", 7)
)

println(Json.prettyPrint(Json.toJson(people)))
```

See here the [scalafiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/6lKNfL9/0)

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

sealed trait Person {
  val name: String
}

final case class Teacher(name: String, salary: Int) extends Person
final case class Student(name: String, grade: Int) extends Person

implicit val teacherWrites: Writes[Teacher] = Json.writes[Teacher]
implicit val studentWrites: Writes[Student] = Json.writes[Student]

implicit val personWrites: Writes[Person] = Writes[Person] {
  case t: Teacher => Json.toJson(t)(teacherWrites)
  case s: Student => Json.toJson(s)(studentWrites)
}

val people = List[Person] (
  Teacher("Jane Doe", 40000),
  Student("Alice", 5),
  Student("Bob", 7)
)

Json.prettyPrint(Json.toJson(people))
```

The trick is adding `teacherWrites` and `studentWrites` explicitly. Because they are both `Person`s, before it was recognizing them as such and calling your `personWrites` again, hence the stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks. Sure, this will do. But in real life I have many more case classes, and the goal of whole exercise with base sealed trait was to avoid writing per-class code.

Comment: @DmitryShkolnik Yeah unfortunately I've never found a way around that with play-json.